# Can such a predicate exist?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, logic, proof-explanation, predicate-logic

Given a set of conditions listed below:

For some predicate $P(n), P(1)$ and $P(2)$ are True, but $[(\forall n ≥ 3)(P(n) \implies P(n + 1))]$ is False
Does this predicate exist or not? Give an example or provide reasoning.

I feel as if this couldn't exist. For all $n$ greater or equal to three, $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ to be false, $P(n)$ must be true and $P(n+1)$ must be false. Given an arbitrary $m$, where $m = n+1$, then for the same statement $P(m) \implies P(m+1)$, then $P(m)$ must be true and $P(m+1)$ must be false. But we've already stated that $P(m) = P(k+1)$ which must be false, creating a contradiction.

Likewise, another example would be $P(1)$ is True, $P(k) \implies P(k + 1)$ is False for all $k \in \mathbb N$.

Apologies for formatting issues, I am still new to this site :)

Comment: What about the case when $P(n) := n<4$? Then $P(1)$, $P(2)$, and $P(3)$ are true but clearly it is not the case that $[(\forall n geq 3)(P(n) \implies P(n+1)]$ since $P(3)$ but $\neg P(4)$.

Comment: It seems that this question is just asking you to show that proving something holds for the first three cases is not sufficient to show that it holds for all $\mathbb{N}$ (a classic joke among undergraduates about misunderstanding the principle of induction)

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: @JackCrawford Wow, this went right over my head. I feel like a complete dummy now. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Oops, didn't know that was a must. I've never used it before but I'll start now

Comment: @JackCrawford Just a question, however: if that was a possible predicate, then if we extended the cases, wouldn't there still be an issue? If n = 4, then both P(n)⟹P(n+1) are false, which would give true as an output. I'm not sure if I am missing something here.

Comment: @GaryCong Yes — In my example it’s true for all values of $n>3$, but it is false in particular when $n=3$, so we still fail to satisfy the $\forall n \geq 3$ condition. “For all” really does mean “for *all*”.

Answer (score 1):

$\lnot \forall n{\in}\Bbb N_{\geq 3}~(P(n)\to P(n+1))$ is *not* equivalent to $\forall n{\in}\Bbb N_{\geq 3}~\lnot(P(n)\to P(n+1))$.

You just require $\exists n{\in}\Bbb N_{\geq 3}~(P(n)\land\lnot P(n+1))$

So $P(0),P(1),P(2),P(3),\lnot P(4),\ldots$ will suffice.